# How to restore from SQL Server 2005 backup

Tags: sql-server-2005

I ran a backup of my SQL Server database using the backup utility in the Server GUI. The backup works fine and I can restore on that machine without issue. I cannot, however, restore the backup on another machine. It starts to load and everything looks ok, but the 'restore' process just sits idle forever (I say forever as I let it run for 6 hours one day with no sign of completing. This is only a 1GB database so the restore time should be quick.)

This was on a backup database that had the exact same version of SQL Server and even the same schema. Is there something I am missing?  Is there a better way to do a recovery on another server?

Comment: or [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Does that "other machine" also have SQL Server 2005 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Do both SQL servers have the same service pack?  If you do the restore, did you check the "overwrite" option on the database restore?

It should work.  The only type of backup that I believe might (in some cases) normally fail on the GUI is a "copy only backup", which it doesn't seem like you made.

Comment: The servers have the same service pack as they're VM's built from the same image.  I do not see a "copy only backup" option as I make the backup. I did try the 'overwrite' option this time but I get the following error with/without that at this point:  "Restore Failed for Server 'MyServer'  Additional Information:   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:   RESTORE cannot process database 'MyDB' because it is in use by this session.

Comment: Then, you should verify that you can restore the backup into a brand new database with a different name.  This is easy to do with Management Studio.  If you cannot do that, then you wont be able to restore onto an existing database name either.

Comment: The database name is the exact same.  The server has a different host name obviously but the name of the database is identical to the primary one.

Comment: If everything else fails, then install SQL 2008 R2 and use the SQL Server Studio Managment tool to export the data using either Export or a SSIS transaction, bypassing the backup-restore method. Unfortunately, SQL 2005 Express doesn't have the export feature.  In my experience with 2005, backup/restore has worked flawlessly, and so I am not sure what else to suggest.